# How do you show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \sin(\pi/n)$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I'm a bit lost because I know that the alternating series test doesn't apply here.  I've shown that it does not converge absolutely using the limit comparison test, but right now the only way I know this series actually converges is by typing it into Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Which hypothesis of the alternating series test is not satisfied?

Comment: The $sin(\pi/n)$'s do not monotonically converge to 0...$sin(\pi) = 0$, then $sin(\pi/2) = 1$, after $\pi/2$, then we start converging to 0, but I thought the increase between the first and second terms meant it can't be monotonically decreasing.

Comment: You can always split an infinite sum into a finite prefix and an infinite "everything after that".  Alternatively, you can restate your theorems to use come version of "eventually" more often (that is, "there is an $N$ such that for all $n > N$...").  For instance, "suppose the magnitude of the terms is eventually monotonically decreasing...".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although $\sin\left( \frac{\pi}{n} \right)$ is increasing for $1 < n < 2$, the sum can be split up to $$(-1)^1 \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{1} \right) +\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (-1)^n \sin\left( \frac{\pi}{n} \right)$$. Then from there, you can use the [Alternating Series Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

After you remove the $n=1$ case, what can you say about $\sin(\pi/n)$?

Comment: then it is monotonically decreasing and converges to 0

Comment: This answer is correct. I don't see why there should be a downvote.

Answer (score 2):

When $n$ is sufficiently large, there exists a constant $C>0$ such that $|\sin(\pi/n)-\sin(\pi/(n+1))|\leq C/n^2$. (justify yourself) Then, simply $$\Big|\sum_{n=k}^l\sin(\pi/2n)-\sin(\pi/(2n+1))\Big|\leq \frac{C}{4}\sum_{n=k}^ln^{-2}\xrightarrow{k,l\rightarrow \infty}0,$$ hence the sequence $\{\sum_{n=1}^k\sin(\pi/(2n+1))-\sin(\pi/2n)\}_k$ is a Cauchy sequence, therefore by completeness of $\mathbb{R}$ it converges : $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\sin(\pi/n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin(\pi/2n)-\sin(\pi/(2n+1)).$$ And the reason we can change summation is $|\sin(\pi/n)|\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty} 0$.